# Implementar bucle while dentro de bucle for

Tags: javascript

Tengo estas variables declaradas:

```js
 var toReturn = 96.74

 var myBank = 335.409

 var typeofCoin = [0.01,0.05,0.10,0.25,1,5,10,20,100]

 var quantityeachCoin = [ 1.01, 2.05, 3.1, 4.25, 90, 55, 20, 60, 100 ]

  var quantityofCoins = [ 101, 41, 31, 17, 90, 11, 2, 3, 1 ]

  var cidtoReturn = [["PENNY", 0], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE",0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]
```

Lo que espero con el siguiente código es devolver el array `cidtoReturn` populado con la cantidad de monedas exactas que sumadas dan como resultado el valor de `toReturn` debe ser ordenado de mayor moneda a menor.
El resultado ideal sería el siguiente:

```
cidtoReturn = [["TWENTY", 60], ["TEN", 20], ["FIVE", 15], ["ONE", 1], ["QUARTER", 0.5], ["DIME", 0.2], ["PENNY", 0.04]]
```

Como veis si sumáis cada uno de los valores de este array el resultado es 96.74, es decir, el valor de `toReturn`

Para conseguir esto he escrito lo siguiente:

```js
var reference = 0 //stop loop when reference value becomes 96.74
  for (var i=cidtoReturn.length; i > -1; i--){
    let counter = quantityofCoins[i]
    while (reference < toReturn){
      if (reference === toReturn) {
          break;
        }
      for (var j=0; j<counter;j++){
        cidtoReturn[i][1] += typeofCoin[i]
        reference += typeofCoin[i]
      }
    }
  }
```

Lo que hago en este código es:
1.Creo la variable `reference` para usarla como "tope"
2. Hago un bucle para ir a través de cada moneda. Desde más grande a más pequeña.
3. Hago una variable contador para asegurarme que no uso más monedas de las que hay disponibles (por ejemplo, no puedo usar más de 3 veces la moneda 20$ porque sólo tengo 3 monedas de 20$ como veis en la variable `quantityofCoins`)

A partir de ese razonamiento hago el bucle while para hacer funcionar a `reference` como "tope" pero no funciona pero porque nunca se llega a cumplir `reference === toReturn`

Comment: el if de reference === to return está dentro de un while reference < toReturn. Obviamente, las dos cosas a la vez nunca se cumplirán y no entrará en el if.

Comment: Entiendo, y cómo puedo modificar el while para que entre en el if pero a la vez me asegure que reference no pasa de 96.74?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira a ver si el siguiente código te funcionaría. El While y el if te sobraban.

```
var reference = 0 //stop loop when reference value becomes 96.74
   for (var i=cidtoReturn.length; i > -1; i--){
       let counter = quantityofCoins[i]
       for (var j=0; j<counter;j++){
          if (reference + typeofCoin[i] <= toReturn){
               cidtoReturn[i][1] += typeofCoin[i]
               reference += typeofCoin[i]
          }
          else {
             break
          }
       }
    }
```